# Apache POI - Word Files

Tags: apache, ms-word, format, apache-poi

1. I have been successfully able to read a word document containing images usiong POI.
2. I have even be able to extract a section from Word document including the images.
3. I am writing the extracted portion containg images to a new word document.
4. My problem is that I have to display this extracted portion (containing text, fonts, colors images) on the screen using any standard Java Swing component.

Please advise how can I do that?

I tried JText, Panel, editor but all would take only text and I loose my formatting and images.

Regards